# How to get write callback while piping two tcp streams in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

If two TCP streams are being piped then I need a write callback for the writable stream.

```
readableSocket.pipe(writableSocket)
```

I want callback as we give in case of manual writing to stream like -

```
writableSocket.write("", function callback() {})
```

Comment: How we are supposed to help you? :)

Comment: Is there any event I can put on writableSocket while keeping my pipe intact to achieve this :)

Comment: Good question, you can now edit your post with this one.

Comment: So you're asking if there is a callback that will be called after this specific chunk is written?

Comment: @NimitAggarwal I may have a solution for you, but I'm not sure if you're interested in using standard streams or you just want to make sure that that action is done. My framework [scramjet](https://www.scramjet.org/) could be used to act as you want and it extends standard streams. Let me know if that could be what you need

Comment: Essentially yes @Michal

Comment: Ok, then take a look at [DataStream..whenWrote](https://www.scramjet.org/docs/data-stream#DataStream+whenWrote) - it's a method that allows you to get a callback for writing easily. You need to take into account two aspects though: `maxParallel` option for scramjet and `highWaterMark` option for node streams - if both are set to `0` you should get the callback working as expected.

Comment: If that satisfies your requirements - I can post an answer here with some code.